# XML Encryption and Decryption

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to encrypt and decrypt my xml file.
I read w3c recommendation about this process.
by some searching 
I found npm xml-encryption 1.2.0
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-encryption
Has anyone tried it before?
I've installed it but it shows me that error
 *"require is not defined"*
**Have you guys any other ways to encrypt xml?**

my code

```
<html>
  <head>
<script>
var xmlenc = require('xml-encryption');
var options = {
  rsa_pub: fs.readFileSync('./public.pem'),
  pem: fs.readFileSync('./public.pem'),
  encryptionAlgorithm: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc',
  keyEncryptionAlgorithm: 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p',
  disallowEncryptionWithInsecureAlgorithm: true,
  warnInsecureAlgorithm: true
};

xmlenc.encrypt('content to encrypt', options, function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: XML is just text, you can encrypt it any way you want.

Comment: I know that but,I have to use XML Encryption _the whole xml document_ depending on w3c recommendation,do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here
*[Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)*
firstly I thought this error is related to the package xml-encryption because I already have installed nodejs